# Postgresql primary key not auto incrementing even when notation serial specified using .net core

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Postgresql primary key not auto incrementing even when notation serial specified
this is my table create script

```
CREATE TABLE public."Medication" (
    "Id" serial NOT NULL,
    "ResidentId" int4 NOT NULL,
    "PharmacyId" int4 NULL,
    "PhysicianId" int4 NULL,
    "ReleasedQty" float8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'::double precision,
    "PRNEffectiveTime" int4 NULL,
    "IsSTO" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    "IsPendingOrder" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    "IsPsychotropic" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    "IsINRRequired" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    "eSignature" varchar NULL,
    "eSignatureDate" timestamp NULL,
    "PhysicianId_X" int4 NULL,
    "IsWitnessSigReq" bool NULL,
    "IsInjection" bool NULL,
    "AdministerByRole" varchar NULL,
    "AdministerByUser" varchar NULL,
    "AlfId" int4 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Medication_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id", "AlfId")
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ("AlfId");
```

the value of **Id** always remains zero

Comment: Then you are apparently explicitly inserting `0` into that column.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: I am using .net core to insert data and then it is happening

Comment: let me check if it contains value zero explicitly

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please post 0 value comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My query was inserting explicit value **0**
and this was happening in .net core with Medication Object containing Id zero.
when in my class I specified Id as Identity column then it fixed

```
Table("Medication")]
    public partial class Medication
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
```

I was not adding **[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]** and this is why it was happening